# Microsoft Graph API - Unable to filter with endswith

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

To filter Microsoft Graph API responses, the docs suggest to use the `filter` query option.

Here I've used `startswith` and `endswith` string functions on the `'/me/messages'` endpoint.

```
query = {
    '$filter': "
      startswith(from/emailAddress/address, 'abcd')
      or endswith(from/emailAddress/address, 'gmail.com')"
  }
```

Only using `startswith` returns the expected response. On adding the `endswith` function to the filter query, the response received is an error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter",
    "message": "The query filter contains one or more invalid nodes.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "0d12e1f6-6105-4826-9656-8613f8c167ed",
      "date": "2019-03-14T11:05:56"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems as at today, this doesn't work and has been an open issue for over a year. See the issue here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4331

Comment: Hey @friek108, yup that issue was raised by myself a couple years ago :)

Comment: Hi Tejas, endswith is now working on mail and userPrincipalName. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983320/endswith-filter-not-supported/66137749#66137749 for a Graph Explorer and Graph.Net SDK example.

Answer (score 5):

To use $filter with endsWith you need to:

1. Add $count=true to the query parameters
2. Add ConsistencyLevel: eventual request header

Example : 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$filter=endswith(mail,'@hotmail.com')'

**It works for mail and userPrincipalName but not for displayName

Answer (score 0):

Copied this exact same query (with the ConsistencyLevel either in the query params or headers params and wasn't able to make it work. The app that I used to request authorisation token have Users.ReadWrite.All permission AND the User.Read.All.

In Postman :

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$filter=endswith(mail,'@hotmail.com')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$count=true&ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$filter=endswith(mail,%27@hotmail.com%27))

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported property filter clause operator 'SuffixMatch'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-07-27T13:22:38",
            "request-id": "3f509514-4e77-4eb1-8557-0fe102d502f5",
            "client-request-id": "3f509514-4e77-4eb1-8557-0fe102d502f5"
        }
    }
}
```

----- **EDIT** ------

---

Just found my answer here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

Use of $count is not supported in Azure AD B2C tenants.