# endsWith filter not supported?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName,'P')
```

works like a charm, whereas

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=endsWith(displayName,'z')
```

throws a 400 error

Any idea why endsWith is not supported ?

Comment: This is a question that has been asked. Although UserVoice has voted a lot, it still does not support filters such as "endswith". see: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4331

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment moved to answer：

This is a question that has been asked. Although UserVoice has voted a lot, it still does not support filters such as "endswith". see:[here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4331).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is still not working for displayName. But for mail and userPrincipalName the following works (since recently).

Graph explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0//users?$count=true&$filter=endsWith(userPrincipalName,'@example.com')&$select=id,userPrincipalName
```

Graph.NET SDK:

```
var request = graphServiceClient.Users
                .Request()
                .Header("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
                .Filter("endswith(userPrincipalName,'@example.com')")
                .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.UserPrincipalName })
                .OrderBy("userPrincipalName");
request.QueryOptions.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));

var result = await request.GetAsync();
```

See also example 5 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp (at this moment the C# example in the docs is incomplete)